# Manage objects in class for PO mechanism

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

I am practicing selenium automation using JAVA on OrangeHRM website.

Scenario:
Login
Navigate Admin link
Add user to search
...

I created 3 pages viz.
LoginPage
HomePage
AdminPage

In each page, identified elements & passed appropriate arguments:

For e.g. in login page:

```
@FindBy(id="txtUsername")
WebElement txt_userName;

@FindBy(id="txtPassword")
WebElement txt_password;

@FindBy(id="btnLogin")
WebElement btn_login;

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

public void enterUserName (String userid) {
    txt_userName.sendKeys(userid);
}

public void enterUserPassword (String userpassword) {
    txt_password.sendKeys(userpassword);
}

public void clickLoginbutton () {
    btn_login.click();
}
```

Now in main class file, when I try to replay above scenario:

Each time I have to create object of pages to utilize methods:

```
package xyz;

imports ****;

public class SearchUser {
    
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String baseURL;

    public void browser_open(){
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        baseURL = "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com";
        driver.get(baseURL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }

    public void login_user(String userid, String userpassword){
        lgnp = new LoginPage(driver);

        lgnp.enterUserName(userid);
        lgnp.enterUserPassword(userpassword);
        lgnp.clickLoginbutton();
    }

    public void navigate_admin(){

        hp = new HomePage(driver);

        Actions a = new Actions(driver);
        a.moveToElement(hp.lnk_admin()).click().build().perform();
    }

    public void click_search(){

        ap = new AdminPage(driver);

        ap.btn_search();
    }
    
    public void add_user(String usersearch){

        ap = new AdminPage(driver);

        ap.txt_emplUserName(usersearch);

    }

    public void logout(){

        hp = new HomePage(driver);

        hp.lnk_welcome();
        hp.lnk_logout();

        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Do we have any way to avoid creating objects each time in each class?
I tried to implement Page Object Manager using link (https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/page-object-manager/), but its not working.

Also tried to define objects at global level, but script retruns NLP.

Do we have any ways to manage objects or references?

TIA.

Comment: " tried to implement Page Object Manager using link (https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/page-object-manager/), but its not working." - when you have taken some trial that did not work, don't just mention that. Provide details.

Comment: Hi Alexey R.,
Realized my mistake.
I wasn't instantiating page defined in my page object manager and hence its not working.
Now issue resolved.
Thanks.